# plugins for my android app

Tags: android, plugins

I'm trying to find out what is the right method of enabling plugins or extensions for my android application. As with any other plug-able application I want:
1) list of installed plugins
2) ability to call methods (which may or may not have UI) implemented in plugins

Goal is to isolate functionality which is not essential.

Ondra

Answer (score 2):

Its not really clear what you mean. If you want to develop your own reusable app components using and Android Library Project maybe what you want [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject), or else you may want to look into how Content Providers and Intents are used to use other installed applications on the device [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to clarify. I want to give ability to add ad-hoc features to my application (even other developers then me could add new features). Without exposing code of my application. And I want user to install this extra features separately from main application.

Comment: I'm not looking for (compile time) libraries. Separate Activities/Content Providers may do the job - but how can I get/maintain list of related Activities. And more - plugins are not meant to run as standalone applications (which separate activity is). Could Content Providers have some UI which show up on data request?